# where should I place my block,container and layout files in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

how should I  create a custom layout file , custom container and add custom blocks to containers? I dont know where to place which one. can anybody give an example of adding a block that says "hello" to the container using custom layout I am new to magento. I am learning! please help

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framewrk:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="empty"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">

<container name="header.container" as="header.container" label="Pag Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>

<container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>


<container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />


</referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

I created a E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\app\design\frontend\vendor\my_new_theme\Magento_Theme\page-layout\test-layout.xml  and registered in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\app\design\frontend\vendor\my_new_theme\Magento_Theme\layouts.xml
where should my blocks go?

Comment: You can have look at official documentation. Things are explained well there. Go for example: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html,  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html

Comment: Its bit confusing @Jai

Comment: Check @Manoj's answer. Comment below if you have any confusion. We will clear that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding your custom theme , you can place your custom code in default.xml

/app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

For Custom container: `<container name="test.container" as="testContainer" label="test Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-container" />`

For adding/removing something from test container use referenceContainer  :

For example you have some content says " hello" in hello-block.html placed in Magento_Theme module then call the file in your custom container.

```
<referenceContainer name="test.container">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="hello-block" template="Magento_Theme::hello-block.phtml"/></referenceContainer>
```

For removing something , for ex Remove whishlist:

```
<referenceContainer name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
```

For adding content through admin block and then calling block in html file use

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="hello-block"}}</div>
```

For calling static resources , your custom css and js  adding bootstrap, call files in default_head_blocks.xml

app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Place both files under /app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/web/css or js

Remove existing css and js

```
<remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
```

I hope these things will help you to some extent

Comment: Its working..!! what is the class attribute in block?

Comment: class attribute  implements rendering of a particular block. Basically take care of actual rendering of block out put.

for more details on each attribute of block ,checkout this ... http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link https://webkul.com/blog/create-hello-module-in-magento2/.. I have learnt from the website and follow each and every step. It works well.

Comment: this is clear!!! But I wanted to create my own layout design..!! how come i do this??

Comment: Link-only answer. Please see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers